# Count Items in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble counting my arrays how someone can help.

```
Array
(
    [2014-06-17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40404
                    [client] => Client 1
                    [date] => 2014-06-17T14:57:08+0100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40403
                    [client] => Client 1
                    [date] => 2014-06-17T14:39:02+0100
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 40402
                    [client] => Client 2
                    [date] => 2014-06-17T13:34:18+0100
                )

        )

)
```

I would like filter this array after I created it to look like this.

```
Array
(
    [2014-06-17] => Array
        (
            [Client 1] => Array
                (
                    [submitted] => 2
                )

            [Client 2] => Array
                (
                    [submitted] => 1

                )
)
```

Currently my code looks like this, i'm guessing I need another foreach to filter this more but i'm stuck filting this array.

```
    foreach ($submissions as $sortArray) {
        $dataJson[substr($sortArray['thing']['created'], 0, 10)][] = array(
            'id' => $sortArray['id'],
            'client' => $sortArray['thing']['client']['name'],
            'date' => $sortArray['thing']['created']
        );
        $filterd = $dataJson;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($filterd);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$result = array();

foreach($source as $day => $orders) {
    $clients = array();
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if (!isset($clients[$order['client']])) {
            $clients[$order['client']] = array('submitted' => 1);
        }
        else {
            $clients[$order['client']]['submitted']++;
        }
    }
    $result[$day] = $clients;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop and use the client's identifier as an array key:

```
foreach($submissions as $d)
{
    if(isset($counts[$d['client']]))
        $counts[$d['client']] = 1;
    else
        $counts[$d['client']]+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
 $array = array();
 foreach($submissions as $submission){
       $array[$submission['client']]['submitted'] = isset($array[$submission['client']]['submitted'])? ($array[$submission['client']]['submitted'] + 1): 1;
 }
```